# Button position changes when acessing blog from different links

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, css-position

I've embed a wordpress blog in my company page but it is having a stranger behavior regarding a button in my header. If I go to the site coming from the blog homepage https://www.racheaqui.com.br/blog and click in any post to open its detailed single page, it goes ok with the button "CADASTRE SUA LOJA" just right from "ENTRE EM CONTATO". But if I copy and paste, or if i click in a link direct to the post, from Chrome navigator, example: https://www.racheaqui.com.br/blog/tecnologia/instagram-ganha-novos-recursos/ the button "CADASTRE SUA LOJA" changes its position and appears under the "ENTRE EM CONTATO". The destination post link is exactly the same in both cases. Anyone have an idea why does it occours?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is odd. Note that your `.menu ul` has invalid markup:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  ...
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Changing the <a> to outside the </ul> solved the problem. Thanks a lot, Isherwood. I'd not noticed that.